# Postgresql count based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am executing this query

```
SELECT COUNT(designer_orders.id) as pr, 
       SUM(IF designer_orders.package_status == 'packed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as pu 
FROM "designer_orders"
```

Expected output

```
PR PU
10 5
```

Getting Output

```
PR PU
10 0
```

This block of query not working as expected

```
SUM(IF designer_orders.package_status == 'packed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Comment: That query will not work at all because SQL does not have an `IF` statement. You need to use `CASE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i just saw if in postgresql documentation. by the way how do i use 'CASE'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(designer_orders.id) as pr, SUM(CASE WHEN designer_orders.package_status = 'packed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as pu FROM "designer_orders"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `IF` in SQL, you need to use `CASE`.

Additionally the equality operator in SQL is  `=` not `==`

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as pr, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN package_status = 'packed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as pu 
FROM designer_orders;
```

For an introduction into SQL, please see this chapter of the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-sql.html

For a description of available operators, please see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: `CASE WHEN` should be used here